# Getting error while using split method for reading multiple integers in a single line

Tags: c#, split

I am getting an error while using `Split` while reading an integer from the user

```
 int[] a = new int[s];
        for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            a[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '));
        }
```

Can you please help me how to use `Split`.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What does the user input look like? "1 2 3 4 5"?

Comment: What purpose does this code serve? Do you intend to call Console.ReadLine() 's' number of times? A sample input and expected output will be appreciated !

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Its giving me an overload error near split method.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take the input as string first

```
   string[] array_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
```

and then convert the array into Int

```
   int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(array_temp,Int32.Parse);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since split returns an array, and each time you need the i'ed one, you should change it like this:

```
 int[] a = new int[s];
 string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

 for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
 {
    a[i] = Int32.Parse(input[i]);
 }
```

You need to read the input only once btw.
Like *@loneshark99* said it would be even better to use TryParse(). Since that returns a boolean, you can check if the input are indeed integers. If you just use Parse and they are not integers, it would throw an exception.

Code with TryParse():

```
 int[] a = new int[s];
 string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

 for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
 {
    if (Int32.TryParse(input[i], out a[i])) 
    {
        //successfully parsed
    }
 }
```

The if-statement is not necessary but it's just to point out how you could use the TryParse.

Comment: You should probably use the TryParse method, instead of Parse since its a user input.

Comment: I'd also move the split outside of the loop so you're not splitting the string `s` times.

Comment: @loneshark99 I added it to the solution. ;)

Answer (score 3):

LINQ can really help you here:

```
int[] a = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```